# How to reduce rails code efficiently?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Projects controller I have 5 methods:

```
def day1
end

def day2
end

def day3
end

def day4
end

def day5
end
```

In the views I have:

```
day1.html.erb
day2.html.erb
day3.html.erb
day4.html.erb
day5.html.erb
```

In each individual view, I have a block of code similar to this:

In day1.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin? %>
  "Display Day 1"
<% else %>
  <% unless current_user.day_count.nil? %>
    <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 1 %>
      "Display Day 1"
    <% else %>
      "This project cannot open now. Please wait until day1!"
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In day2.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin? %>
  "Display Day 2"
<% else %>
  <% unless current_user.day_count.nil? %>
    <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 2 %>
      "Display Day 2"
    <% else %>
      "This project cannot open now. Please wait until day2!"
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and so on, so on... until day 5.

In the routes.rb:

```
match 'projects/day-1' => "projects#day1", :via => [:get], as: "day1"
match 'projects/day-2' => "projects#day2", :via => [:get], as: "day2"
match 'projects/day-3' => "projects#day3", :via => [:get], as: "day3"
match 'projects/day-4' => "projects#day4", :via => [:get], as: "day4"
match 'projects/day-5' => "projects#day5", :via => [:get], as: "day5"
```

And in index.html.erb views I have:

```
<% if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin? %>
  <div class="day_tracking">
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>4</p></div>
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>5</p></div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <% unless current_user.day_count.nil? %>
    <div class="day_tracking">
      <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 1 %>
        <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>1</p></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p>1</p></div>
      <% end %>

      <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 2 %>
        <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>2</p></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p>2</p></div>
      <% end %>

      <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 3 %>
        <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>3</p></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p>3</p></div>
      <% end %>

      <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 4 %>
        <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>4</p></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p>4</p></div>
      <% end %>

      <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= 5 %>
        <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p>5</p></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p>5</p></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What the code does is very simple. First, I check to see if the current_user is an admin or a speed user or not. If he is, then display:

```
✔1 ✔2 ✔3 ✔4 ✔5 
( It means he can see all the projects )
```

Else, If the current_user is not a speed user or an admin, then display:

```
✔1 ✘2 ✘3 ✘4 ✘5 
( It means he can only see the number of projects 
equivalent to his day_count ---- in case day_count not nil!)
```

For Example:

- If the current_user have day_count = 1, then he can only see project 1:

  ✔1 ✘2 ✘3 ✘4 ✘5
- If the curent_user have day_count = 2, then he can only see project 1 and 2:

  ✔1 ✔2 ✘3 ✘4 ✘5

... And so on, so on....

The code is simple, but quite repetitive. I know it's a bad way of coding , but still cannot figure out how to reduce it efficiently and effectively. If I have more than 30 days, the code can go on, go on to more than 2,000 lines of code and probably will make the program become slow down!

Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use day as parameter like `project/days?day=1`

Comment: Thank you, but I still want to have the url: `projects/day-1`  for SEO sake and for other reasons. How about reducing code in index.html.erb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes

```
match 'projects/days/(:day)' => "projects#day", :via => [:get], as: "day"
```

views

```
day.html.erb

<% if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin? %>
  "Display Day #{@day}"
<% else %>
<% unless current_user.day_count.nil? %>
  <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= @day %>
    "Display Day #{@day}"
  <% else %>
    "This project cannot open now. Please wait until day#{@day}!"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def day
  @total_days = 5
  @day = params[:day]
end
```

index.html

```
<% if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin? %>
  <div class="day_tracking">
    <% @total_days.each do |day| %>
    <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p><%= day %></p></div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <% unless current_user.day_count.nil? %>
    <div class="day_tracking">
      <% @total_days.each do |day| %>
        <% if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= day %>
          <div class="day_passed"><span>✔</span><p><%= day %></p></div>
        <% else %>
          <div class="day_left"><span>✘</span><p><%= day %></p></div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can like this. There are more refactoring point, It is just concept.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exellent code! You saved me 1,000 lines of code! :-))

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily re-factored. One of the main tenets of Ruby is the DRY principle and your design goes against it.

Change your route according to this.

```
match 'projects/:days' => "projects#show_project", :via => [:get]
```

In your controller you should have this.

```
def show_project
end
```

Transfer the business logic to the project model.

```
def has_access?(no_of_days)
  return true if current_user.speed? || current_user.admin?
  unless current_user.day_count.nil?
    if (Time.now.to_date - current_user.day_count.to_date).to_i + 1 >= no_of_days
      true
    else 
      false
  end
end
```

Now in your view its as simple as.

```
 <% if @project.has_access?(params[:days]) %>
   "Display Day #{params[:days]}"
 <% else %>
   "This project cannot open now. Please wait until day#{params[:days]}!"
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is concise. I'll implement it!